# How to display a ::after pseudo-element over all the elements on the page when its parent has a vertical scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I use `overflow-y: scroll` on a `div`, then its children `div`s `::after` elements are displayed under some element. When I don't use `overflow-y: scroll` everything looks perfect except the scrollbar is no longer displayed.

I've already tried "z-index" on the `::after` elements, but it doesn't change anything.

```css
#servers-cont {
  flex: 0 0 120px;
}

/* Uncomment to display the scrollbar, but then ".server-circle:hover:after" is not completely visible */
/*
#servers-cont {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
*/

.server-circle {
  background: blue !important;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.server-circle:hover {
  background: red !important;
}

.server-circle:hover:after {
  content: "AAAAAAAAAAAA";
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div class="row" id="all-conts">
  <div class="col" id="servers-cont">
    <div class="server-circle" data-name="a"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="server-circle"></div>
    <div class="server-circle"></div>
    <div class="server-circle"></div>
    <div class="server-circle"></div>
    <div class="server-circle"></div>
    <div class="server-circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/VeryKnave/pen/oNvJqxN?editors=1000)

I expect that the "::after" elements to be completely visible when `#servers-cont {overflow-y: scroll}`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to place a pseudo class such as :after or :before outside of the element if that element has an overflow scroll enabled. However try to send us a screenshot of the final product/layout, perhaps there is a work-around without pseudo classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of achieving what you want with the parent container settled to have a fixed width with an overflow property.

You need to make the parent width to 100% (or something with enough space to show the full text):

```
#servers-cont {
  width: 100%;
}
```

or auto in flex-basis:

```
#servers-cont {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

`overflow-y: scroll;` means that everything that does not fit on the container (in your case, the container is the element that has the id equal to "servers-cont") would be overflowed.

You have explicitly settled a widget on that element via `flex: 0 0 120px;`.

You don't see the scroll bar unless you do actual scroll. That's just how browsers behave nowadays and there is nothing you can do about it. But the scroll is there!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As the other comment and reply says, you cannot do that, but I have 2 other solutions:

- You can install a custom scrollbar and see if it works. I installed [simple-scrollbar](https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar) and it worked fine.
- You can replace the pseudo elements with `<p>` or `<div>` tags.